# Pass a table name as a parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure, and pass the name of a table as a parameter and I get this message:**Must declare the table variable "@tblName".**

What do I have to change to make it work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_SaveToErrorLog]
    @tblName as nvarchar(50),
    @subject as nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tblName))
        Begin
            Insert Into @tblName
            (ErrorNumber, ErrorMessage, ErrorProcedure, ErrorState, ErrorSeverity, ErrorLine)
            Select
                ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_LINE()
        End
END
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL, you can't just embed a parameter into a statement like that. See this tip [part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use a variable containing the table name in an INSERT statement. The error message is actually occurring because it is expecting a variable that is a table type to insert rows into, but you're passing a variable with a string value.

You can use [Dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to execute the command using a variable table name value like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_SaveToErrorLog]
    @tblName as nvarchar(50),
    @subject as nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tblName))
        Begin
            SET @Sql = 'Insert Into ' + @tblName + '
            (ErrorNumber, ErrorMessage, ErrorProcedure, ErrorState, ErrorSeverity, ErrorLine)
            Select
                ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_LINE()'

            EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
        End
END
```

What this does is dynamically create your T-SQL command and store it in the @Sql variable. The stored procedure [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is then used to execute the T-SQL commands in the @Sql variable, which has the actual table name from the @tblName variable.

Comment: It works just fine. Thanks Andy.